# no match for 'operator=' in '* __result = * __first'

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qlist

I'm trying to copy a QList in a std::vector this is my code:

```
std::copy(_param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs.begin(),
          _param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs.end(),
          listJobs.toVector().toStdVector().begin());



_param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs // is a vector
listJobs // is a QList
```

and error is:

```
no match for 'operator=' in '* __result = * __first'
```

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Really? That is the __full__ error? And what is your question?

Comment: Which object are you trying to copy to which? What are the exact types (including template parameters)? The code you posted doesn't seem to make sense on multiple levels (e.g. it seems to be copying into a temporary vector).

Comment: Why would you even expect that to work? Just copy the elements manually - that takes you a three lines loop and you're done with it. Probably less time that writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toStdVector()` creates a new vector that has the same elements as the Qt collection. Assigning to this vector won't have any effect on the original collection. `toVector()` also just creates a temporary.

I haven't used Qt but it looks like Qt containers can be used pretty much the same as standard containers. So, assuming you're trying to replace the contents of `listJobs` with the contents of `_param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs` I think you can do it like this:

```
listJobs.clear();
std::copy(_param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs.begin(),
          _param_31.listJobs->list_USCOREjobs.end(),
          std::back_inserter(listJobs));
```